# How to build Unity3D-Projects for Holo-Lens using Jenkins and MsBuild on Windows

Tags: windows, batch, visual-studio, jenkins, unity3d

#### Goal

We want to setup automated Builds for our Unity Projects using MSBuild and the MSBuild-Plug-In on Jenkins.

#### My Configuration

The according Build-Step looks like

```
Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild


MSBuild Version                    VisualStudio-MSBuild-15

MSBuild Build File                 E:\Jenkins\workspace\000_BUILD\<MyProjectName>

Command Line Arguments             /m /p:Configuration=Release /p:Plattform=x86

Pass build variables as properties [x]

Do not use chcp command            [ ]
```

and the MSBuild configuration is
[image: MSBuild configuration]

where I'm using MSBuild from our VisualStudio 2017 installation.
This leads in the end to a batch command like

```
cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & E:\VisualStudio\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe /m /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 "E:\Jenkins\workspace\000_BUILDS\MY_PROJECT\My Project.sln" " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
```

Just saying this to make clear that my question is not directly depending on Jenkins.

---

#### My Problem:

I'm getting 72 Error messages, most of them look like (translated from German)

> 2>Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(8,12): error CS0246: The Type or namespace "AssemblyTitleAttribute" was not found (probably a using-Direktive or an Assemblyreference is missing).

some of them also like (translated from German)

> 2>Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(9,32): error CS0518: The predefined type "System.String" is not defined or imported.

---

**Maybe a hint?**
If I build the same project (I stopped the jenkins-job after pulling from git finished) directly within VisualStudio it throws 2 Warnings about some deprecated calls but the AppPackage is builded without any errors.

**And the strange thing**:
After I builded the project succesfully once in VisualStudio, then I also can build the project using MSBuild from command line, get the same output (2 Warnings but no errors) and have my AppPackage builded.

---

#### QUESTION

**What am I doing wrong?

What does VisualStudio from GUI do different from what MSBuild does from command line?

Am I maybe missing a step or an option for MSbuild?**

Comment: I think you should use unityeditor.exe to build a unity project from command line.For this purpose you'll have to create a special class that will be called by unity.

Comment: Ofcourse this already happend before this step. Otherwise there would be no .sln file to be build

Comment: ahaam..Ok then.Any progress on this? I also want to use msbuild with unity (basically for code analisys because I don't know how to generate fxCop command line ,but msbuild knows...)

Comment: Hey @npocmaka I actually solved this quite a while ago ;) I took some time to answer my question so please see below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I didn't restore Nuget-Packages before building using the MSBuild. (Opening Visual-Studio in the GUI it seems to take this step automatically.)

So here is now the complete solution from a Unity-project to an Holo-Lens app-package that finally worked for me:

#### Create Unity CommandLineBuild package

First of all to be able to build a Unity-project via command line you need a special class.

This has to be placed in `/Assets/Editor` of your project:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace JENKINS
{
    public class AutoBuilder : ScriptableObject
    {
        static string[] SCENES = FindEnabledEditorScenes();

        // Use real app name here
        /* Anyway the App will have the name as configured within the Unity-Editor
           This Appname is just for the Folder in which to Build */
        static string APP_NAME;
        static string TARGET_DIR;

        [MenuItem("Custom/CI/Windows Mixed Reality Build (UWP)")]
        public static void PerformWindowsMixedRealityBuild()
        {
            APP_NAME = GetArg("-appName");
            TARGET_DIR = GetArg("-buildFolder");
            Debug.Log("Jenkins-Build: APP_NAME: " + APP_NAME + " TARGET_DIR: " + TARGET_DIR);

            GenericBuild(SCENES, TARGET_DIR + "/" + APP_NAME, BuildTargetGroup.WSA, BuildTarget.WSAPlayer, BuildOptions.AllowDebugging);
        }

        private static string[] FindEnabledEditorScenes()
        {
            List<string> EditorScenes = new List<string>();

            foreach (EditorBuildSettingsScene scene in EditorBuildSettings.scenes)
            {
                if (!scene.enabled) continue;
                EditorScenes.Add(scene.path);
            }

            return EditorScenes.ToArray();
        }

        private static void GenericBuild(string[] scenes, string app_target, BuildTargetGroup build_target_group, BuildTarget build_target, BuildOptions build_options)
        {
            EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget(build_target_group, BuildTarget.WSAPlayer);

            string res = BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, app_target, build_target, build_options);
            if (res.Length > 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("BuildPlayer failure: " + res);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get Arguments from the command line by name
         */
        private static string GetArg(string name)
        {
            var args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                if (args[i] == name && args.Length > i + 1)
                {
                    return args[i + 1];
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But since you don't want to import this package to every project you have, let Jenkins import it on the fly.

Therefor I created the class in an empty project
[image: AutoBuilder.cs in an empty Unity-Project]

and Exportet it as `AutoBuilder.unityproject`:

1. <kbd>right-click</kbd> on `Assets` and click on `Export package...`
   [image][image]
2. Choose a location where to save it to
   (I put mine under `E:\UnityPackage\AutoBuilder.unitypackage`.)

---

## Build Steps

The `Unity-Plugin` and `MSBuild-Plugin` didn't work well for me so I do every step in a dedicated Batch-file.

### 1. Import AutoBuild.unitypackage to the project

First we need to import the before create unitypackage to the actual cloned project.

Run

```
<\Path\To\Your\Unity\Installation\>Editor\Unity.exe -quit -batchmode -username 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' -password 'xxxxxxxxxxx' -logFile uniytImportLog.txt -importPackage E:\UnityPackage\AutoBuilder.unitypackage
```

[Unity - Manual: Command line arguments](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html)

- `-quit`: Make Unity exit after finishing the import
- `-batchmode`: Don't open/load the GUI and emediately exit 1 on any error
- (optional)`-username` and `-password`: Provide your credentials so Unity can lookup your Licence (if needed)
- (optional)`-logFile`: Write the output to a logFile (since Unity in batchmode won't show it!)
- `-importPackage`: Finally tell Unity what to do; in this case import our unitypackage file (Change this to the location you stored `AutoBuilder.unitypackage` to)

### 2. Run the Unity-Build to a Visual-Studio-Solution (.sln)

Now the project is ready to be build via command line to a `.sln` solution.

Run

```
<\Path\To\Your\Unity\Installation\>Editor\Unity.exe -quit -batchmode -username 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' -password 'xxxxxxxxxxx' -logFile uniytBuildLog.txt -buildTarget wsaplayer -executeMethod JENKINS.AutoBuilder.PerformWindowsMixedRealityBuild  -appName %JOB_NAME% -buildFolder %WORKSPACE%\00_BUILD
```

[Unity - Manual: Command line arguments](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html)

- `-quit`: Make Unity exit after finishing the import
- `-batchmode`: Don't open/load the GUI and emediately exit 1 on any error
- (optional)`-username` and `-password`: Provide your credentials so Unity can lookup your Licence (if needed)
- (optional)`-logFile`: Write the output to a logFile (since Unity in batchmode won't show it!)
- `-buildTarget`: Switch to the according build target before loading the project. For app-packages it's e.g. `wsaplayer`
- `-executeMethod`: Finally tell Unity what to do; in this case execute the method from our before imported AutoBuilder class
- `-appName %JOB_NAME%` and `-buildFolder %WORKSPACE%\00_BUILD`: The method we call takes/requires to arguments from the command line.

  - `-appName` sounds a bit missleading since it actually is only the subfolder where Unity will build to. `%JOB_NAME%` is the global Jenkins environment variable for the actual Job's name.
  - `-buildFolder` is the main folder where Unity will build to. `%WORKSPACE%` is the global Jenkins environment variable for the actual Job's workspace folder.

---

**NOTE**
Before the following final two steps, you have to know, how the `.sln` file is called after the Unity-Build.

I will assume from here something like `YourProject.sln` is stored to the variable `App_Name` because it is defined within Unity:

Go to <kbd>Edit</kbd> -> <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Player Settings</kbd>
[image: Go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Player Settings]
and change `Product Name`
[image: Change Product Name]

---

### 3. Restore Nuget-Packages (This was mainly the step I was missing before)

To restore nuget-packages (Visual-Studio usually does this automatically on opening the solution in the GUI) run

```
cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & <Path\To\Your\Visual-Studio\Installation>\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe /m /t:restore /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 "%WORKSPACE%\00_BUILD\%JOB_NAME%\%App_Name%" "
```

[MSBuild Command-Line Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

- `/m`: Specifies the maximum number of concurrent processes to use when building. If you don't include this switch, the default value is 1. If you include this switch without specifying a value, MSBuild will use up to the number of processors in the computer.
- `/t`: Build the specified targets in the project.
- `/p`: Set or override the specified project-level properties, where name is the property name and value is the property value. (-> for Holo-Lens it's `Configuration=Release` and `Plattform=x86`)
- `WORKSPACE`: Jenkins' global environment variable for the actual Job's workspace folder
- `00_BUILD`: we handed this as parameter `-buildFolder` to the Unity build step.
- `JOB_NAME`: Jenkins' global environment variable for the actual Job's name
- `App_Name`: as mentioned before the name of the builded Visual-Studio-Solution (`.sln`)

This will only do the restoring and not build the project yet.

### 4. Build the final App-Package using MSBuild

I didn't like the `MSBuild-Plugin` for jenkins so I made it in a batch file and used the command which was produced by the Plugin before. But doing it in a batch file gave me more flexibility in terms of definig e.g. the target file.

```
cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & <Path\To\Your\Visual-Studio\Installation>\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe /m /t:build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 "%WORKSPACE%\00_BUILD\%JOB_NAME%\%App_Name%" "
```

[MSBuild Command-Line Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

- `/m`: Specifies the maximum number of concurrent processes to use when building. If you don't include this switch, the default value is 1. If you include this switch without specifying a value, MSBuild will use up to the number of processors in the computer.
- `/t`: Build the specified targets in the project.
- `/p`: Set or override the specified project-level properties, where name is the property name and value is the property value. (-> for Holo-Lens it's `Configuration=Release` and `Plattform=x86`)
- `WORKSPACE`: Jenkins' global environment variable for the actual Job's workspace folder
- `00_BUILD`: we handed this as parameter `-buildFolder` to the Unity build step.
- `JOB_NAME`: Jenkins' global environment variable for the actual Job's name
- `App_Name`: as mentioned before the name of the builded Visual-Studio-Solution (`.sln`)

---

### After finishing you now should have the final app-package under

```
%WORKSPACE%\000_BUILD\%JOB_NAME%\%App_Name%\AppPackages
```